# Neural Network script mysteriously doesn't function after optimizations

Tags: python, neural-network

I created a test script for creating a neural network ([On repl.it](https://replit.com/@EarthasaurusRex/Neural-Network-Test#main.py)) based on Sebastian Lague's video about neural networks. Everything functioned correctly up until optimizing the gradient descent using derivatives.

After implementing all the derivatives, the cost of the outputs converge to a seemingly arbitrary value. I did some testing to see if my math was off but everything seemed to work correctly.

One of my guesses is it may have to do with these functions:

```
def ActivationFunction(input):
  input = np.clip(input, -500, 500)
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-input))

def ActivationDerivative(input):
  input = np.clip(input, -500, 500)
  return np.exp(input) / ((np.exp(input) + 1) ** 2)
```

I was getting overflow errors, so I added a min/max to the inputs. The converging value of the cost seems to be based on the min/max values.

The ActivationFunction is a sigmoid function. The ActivationDerivative should be the derivative of that function. These functions worked perfectly fine before trying to implement derivatives to optimize the script.

The only tasks I've assigned the neural network to try to solve is solving an XOR gate and determining whether a binary number is even or odd.

I want to know what exactly might be causing this arbitrary converging cost value and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your derivative is wrong, it should be:

```
def ActivationDerivative(input):
  if -500 < input < 500:
    return np.exp(-input) / ((np.exp(-input) + 1) ** 2)
  else:
    return 0.
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, whether the input is negative or positive has no effect on the equation. The derivative still stays the same.

Comment: comment was more about the "if" part. I don't think this will cause an issue in your case, but it is technically incorrect to do it the way you did